# How to print out nested Arraylist objects and determine their size

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to print out nested ArrayLists. As a Java beginner, i'am not able to do that in a loop. 
My second problem is to find out the size of the nested ArrayList-Objects. ".size()" does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
package java_lernen;

import java.util.*;

public class Java_lernen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dataset ds = new Dataset();
        List<Dataset> db = new ArrayList<>();

        ds.setName("Hans");
        ds.setItem("Hans_one");
        ds.setItem("Hans_two");
        db.add(ds);

        ds.setName("Helga");
        ds.setItem("Helga_one");
        ds.setItem("Helga_two");
        ds.setItem("Helga_three");
        db.add(ds);

        System.out.println(db.size()); // size of database

        System.out.println(db.get(0).getItem(0));
        System.out.println(db.get(0).getItem(1));
        System.out.println(db.get(0).getItem(2));
        // Q1: How can i do this (above) in a loop?

        /* pseudo-code, because i have no idea how to do that!

         for (??? elem: Dataset){
             sout (size of dataset)
         }
         */
        //Q2: How to find out the size of the nested Arraylist(s)
        //.size() doesn't seem to work
    }
}
```

And

```
class Dataset {

    private String name;
    final ArrayList<String> arrayItem;

    public Dataset() {
        arrayItem = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String _name) {
        this.name = _name;
    }

    public void setItem(String _item) {
        arrayItem.add(_item);
    }

    public String getItem(int _nr) {
        String s = arrayItem.get(_nr);
        return s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very misleading constellation. But the for each loop looks like this

```
for(DataSet dataSet : db){
   System.out.println(dataSet.arrayItem.size());
   for(String s : dataSet.arrayItem){
       System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new method in your DataSet class called getSize

```
public int getSize(){
 return arrayItem.size();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the Solution is so obvious, you miss the wood for the trees. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method in DataSet class as *getArrayItem()* instead of using *dataSet.arrayItem* directly and can use the code suggested by @Murat K.

It will look like following.

```
public List<String> getArrayItem(){
    return arrayItem;
}
```

And, the required code will be modified by following:

```
for(DataSet dataSet : db){
   System.out.println(dataSet.getArrayItem().size());
      for(String s : dataSet.getArrayItem()){
           System.out.println(s);
       }
 }
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

add a `Collection` or `array` as member in your `Dataset` class.

```
class Dataset<E> {

    private List<E> items;

    public Dataset() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<E> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    // ... other members and getter/setters
}
```

code to iterate and get size

```
    Dataset<Integer> dataSet = new Dataset<>();
    for (Integer in : dataSet.getItems()) {
        //Iterate
    }
    System.out.println("Size " + dataSet.getItems().size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Complete code for your requirement.

```
package stackOverFlow;

import java.util.*;

public class Java_lernen {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Dataset ds = new Dataset();
    Dataset ds1 = new Dataset();
    List<Dataset> db = new ArrayList<Dataset>();

    ds.setName("Hans");
    ds.setItem("Hans_one");
    ds.setItem("Hans_two");
    db.add(ds);

    ds1.setName("Helga");
    ds1.setItem("Helga_one");
    ds1.setItem("Helga_two");
    ds1.setItem("Helga_three");
    db.add(ds1);

    System.out.println(db.size()); // size of database

    // Q1: How can i do this (above) in a loop?

    /* pseudo-code, because i have no idea how to do that!


     */

    for (Dataset dss : db) {
        System.out.println(dss.getName());
        for (int i = 0; i < dss.getSizeDataset(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\t" + dss.getItem(i));
        }
    }

    //Q2: How to find out the size of the nested Arraylist(s)
    System.out.println(db.get(0).getSizeDataset());
    System.out.println(db.get(1).getSizeDataset());

}
```

}

```
class Dataset {

private String name;
final ArrayList<String> arrayItem;

public Dataset() {
    arrayItem = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String _name) {
    this.name = _name;
}

public void setItem(String _item) {
    arrayItem.add(_item);
}

public String getItem(int _nr) {
    String s = arrayItem.get(_nr);
    return s;
}

public int getSizeDataset() {
    return arrayItem.size();
}

}
```

Comment: you can explain your answer also for a better understanding explaining how this code of yours help solving the problem

Comment: Do you see any disadvantages to use ds = new Dataset(); instead of declaring another dataset? (Dataset ds = new Dataset(); Dataset ds1 = new Dataset();

Comment: When we continuously update only ds object then the name will be overwritten on the existing name and new items will be added the old list. lets take SET-1) name1 , item1, item2 SET-2) name2, item1-1, item1-2 then if we use only one ds then output will be name2, item1, item2, item1-1, item1-2. Here the requirement is list of lists. so we can think the list will be always new one.